# Time Machine seems to ignore external drive

Tags: mac, osx-lion, time-machine

I have an external disk formatted HFS+ case sensitive.  When time machine runs it seems to ignore the entire filesystem on that drive.  The volume name shows up if I dig in to Backs.backupsdb but it's empty.  The logs even report the volume but just note that zero files were backed up.

I see people in my google searches that seem to have no issue getting this to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional details**

- Volume is mounted with a mount point of /home using fstab.
- Volume is formatted CaseSensitive and mounted with ownership enabled.
- According to time machine the disk is not excluded.

  > % tmutil isexcluded /home
  >
  > - /home

Comment: I believe I may have solved this myself, so far it seems as if the mounting in a location other than /Volumes/<VolumeName> is the source of my troubles.  I commented out my stab entry and re-mounted the fs, time machine _seems_ to be backing it up.